# JetBrains (IntelliJ) remove "hotbar" above kubernetes-yml editor

Tags: kubernetes, intellij-idea, yaml, jetbrains-ide

I use IntelliJ from JetBrains. Amongst other things I manage my kubernetes-yml files with it. For that I installed the Kubernetes-Plugin which adds a lot of really useful features but what annoys me a lot is that it also adds a small bar above all files that were detected by it as kubernetes-yml files which offers to apply or delete this file in the cluster.

Since I mostly use kustomize, this feature is pretty useless for me and the bar takes up so much unneccessary space.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to remove, hide or move this bar and couldn't even find where the logic is configured that yml-files with a certain content (this bar only appears when the file contains kubernetes-configuration) will get this bar.

Is there any way to get rid of it?

[image: AnnoyingBar]

[image: AnnoyingBarOutline]

Comment: Do you use the default plug-in from JetBrains or a third-party plug-in? I can't reproduce it with the default Kubernetes plug-in.

Comment: I use the default JetBrain plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10485-kubernetes
The bar didn't appear with older IntelliJ versions. Currently I use 2022.2.3 and the plugin is Version 222.4345.14. I tried downloading the oldest version of the plugin which is still compatible with 2022.2 though (which was 222.3345.3) and there the bar still appeared as well.